# Is there a way to say "method returns this" in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to say "this method returns `this`" using Generics?

Of course, I want to override this method in subclasses, so the declaration should work well with `@Override`.

Here is an example:

```
class Base {
    public Base copyTo (Base dest) {
        ... copy all fields to dest ...
        return this;
    }
}
class X extends Base {
    @Override
    public X copyTo (X dest) {
        super.copyTo (dest);
        ... copy all fields to dest ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

`public <T extends Base> T copyTo (Base dest)` doesn't work at all: I get "Type mismatch: Can't convert from Base to T". If I force it with a cast, the override fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way of expressing that. Just declare the method to return the type of the class. Java has covariant return types, so you can override a method to return a more specific type anyway.

If you wanted to have some marker for this, you could always introduce your own annotation - but don't expect any other tools to take any particular notice of it.

EDIT: the answer from oxbow_lakes does indeed give something which will work in most cases, but I believe there are ways of fooling it such that you're actually dealing with a different type. (From memories of experimentation, anyway.) Note that this is similar to how Java enums work.

Comment: Apart from my (well, Martin Odersky's)  way; detailed above

Comment: Yes, although there are ways of implementing that kind of thing without "This" *actually* being This.

Comment: Well, "This" can be anything which implements the List<A> interface, which because of erasure could be a List of anything. I'd be interested if you could fool it completely

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: sounds like an interesting challenge. How about we define it more precisely before I start having a go... are we just trying to create a valid implementation without any raw types being involved, but where the class is Foo and the add method returns a type other than Foo?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something very clever (and akin to what they have done in Scala with the [2.8 collection framework](http://scaladocs.jcraft.com/2.8.0/)). Declare some interface method that should return "itself" (**Note:** `This` is a type parameter, not a keyword!)

```
public interface Addable<T, This extends Addable<T, This>> {
   public This add(T t);
}
```

Now declare a level of indirection - a "template" class

```
public interface ListTemplate<A, This extends ListTemplate<A, This>> 
    extends Addable<A, This>{
}

public interface List<A> extends ListTemplate<A, List<A>> {
}
```

Then an implementation of `List` has to return a `List` from the `add` method (I'll let you fill in the impl details)

```
public class ListImpl<A> implements List<A> {

    public List<A> add(A a) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Similarly you could have declard a `SetTemplate` and a `Set` to extend the `Addable` interface - the `add` method of which would have returned a `Set`. Cool, huh?

Comment: It does when I try: SubListImpl<A> extends ListImpl<A> and add returns SubListImpl<A> with no compilation issues at all

Comment: Note that there's a difference between "this" and "This". There is no way in Java of forcing a particular instance to be returned from a method; you can only say that a particular type is to be returned. It is not possible in to force that an overriding method returns a sub-type; it only need return a type which is consistent with the method it overrides.

My example was a neat trick using a layer of indirection to make it appear as if a subtype is to be returned. There is only one layer of indirection, however, so it can't be used to further restrict subtypes of ListImpl

Answer (score 0):

using covariant types should be simple as:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {

    Foo<T> get() {
        return this.getClass().cast(this);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

    @Override
    Bar get() {
        return (Bar) super.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd get unchecked type warnings from javac if you did this

Comment: javac (jdk6) gives me no warnings at all. I'm missing something?

Comment: You must be - you've extended a generic class (Foo<T>) but not supplied any type parameters (Bar extends Foo)

Comment: Possibly you have the --Xl: int unchecked flag on (or

Comment: you are right, I'll keep this (wrong) answer for future generations :)