# Java interface with method that returns called object?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to say “method returns this” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091015/is-there-a-way-to-say-method-returns-this-in-java)

I'd like to define an interface in Java with a method whose return type is defined to be the implementing object's type.

```
interface I {
    TYPE doSomething();
} 
class A implements I {
    @Override A doSomething() {
         return this;
    }
}
class B implements I {
    @Override B doSomething() {
         return this;
    }
}
```

etc. What should TYPE be? I've tried doing something like:

```
interface I<T extends I<T>> {
    T doSomething();
} 
class A implements I<A> {
    @Override A doSomething() {
         return this;
    }
}
```

But then you could do something like

```
class B implements I<A> {
    @Override A doSomething() {
         return new A();
    }
}
```

Which I'd like to disallow.

Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, this is basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091015/is-there-a-way-to-say-method-returns-this-in-java

Comment: TYPE should be I because A and B implement I so they both have the type I

Comment: Why do you want to disallow `B implements I<A>`?

Comment: Because B neither implements nor extends A. I want to do something like `b.doSomething().anotherBMethod()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. Best what you could do is to declare the type as the interface itself.

```
interface I {
    I doSomething();
}
```

This does only not *force* the implementor to return the concrete type, but it at least enables the implementor to return the concrete type. You just have to document that properly on the method's javadoc.

See also the [`java.lang.Appendable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) intercace which `StringBuilder` and all other classes implementing the builder pattern does in standard Java SE API.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution because I don't need the extra typing the CRTP solution provides & don't quite see what benefit it provides for my application.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried doing something like:

This is the canonical solution, known as [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (curiously recurring template pattern) in C++.

There’s no way to disallow the `B implements I<A>` code, though. So you’re essentially out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way of doing bound checking based on current class. The possible alternative I thought of is this:

```
public interface I<T extends I> {

    public T doSomething();
}

public class A implements I<A> {

    @Override
    public A doSomething() {
        return new A();
    }
}

public class B implements I<B> {

    @Override
    public B doSomething() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is already in the question.