# Java: How to reference the implementing type of an interface with generics on the interface?

Tags: java, generics

Given:

```
interface Data<M extends Data<?, ?>, T extends Data<?, ?>> {
  M modify(Modifier<M>);
  T transform(Transformer<T>);
}

interface Modifier<M extends Data<?, ?>> {
  M modify(InteralValue a, InternalValue b);
}

interface Transformer<T extends Data<?, ?>> {
  T transform(InteralValue a, InternalValue b);
}
```

Which makes implementors look like this:

```
class A implements Data<A, B> {
  A modify(Modifier<A> modifier) {
     return modifier.modify(this.a, this.b);
  }
  B transform(Transformer<B> transformer) {
     return transformer.transform(this.a, this.b);
  }
}

class B implements Data<B, C> {
  B modify(Modifier<B> modifier) {
     return modifier.modify(this.a, this.b);
  }
  C transform(Transformer<C> transformer) {
     return transformer.transform(this.a, this.b);
  }
}
... and so for C, D, etc...
```

Is it possible to either limit M to be only the current implementor of Data (in this case A), or remove M altogether (reference M in such a way the current interface implementor is the limiter of M)?

To clarify, the transform function is intended to change from one type to the next (B b = A.transform(Z) where Z is a Transformer), while the modify function is intended to return the same type, but with different internals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to say "method returns this" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091015/is-there-a-way-to-say-method-returns-this-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit M to be only A,remove M altogether and keep only T

```
interface Data<T extends Data<?, ?>> {
  A modify(Modifier);
  T transform(Transformer<T>);
}

interface Modifier {
  A modify(InteralValue a, InternalValue b);
}

interface Transformer<T extends Data<?, ?>> {
  T transform(InteralValue a, InternalValue b);
}
Which makes implementors look like this:

class A implements Data<B> {
  A modify(Modifier modifier) {
     return modifier.modify(this.a, this.b);
  }
  B transform(Transformer<B> transformer) {
     return transformer.transform(this.a, this.b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, let me clarify the question:

A is only a single implementor. There are potential multiple ones, so just referring to A is too limiting.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to refer to the type of the implementing class in Java. If it were possible to do this, it would cause problems with inheritance that cannot be handled by the current type system in Java:

```
interface Foo {
    Self foo();
}
class Bar implements Foo {
    Bar foo() { return new Bar(); }
}
class Baz extends Bar { }
```

Interface implementation is inherited in Java, so `Baz` should implement the interface `Foo`; however, `Baz` does not implement a `foo()` method that returns `Baz`, as required by interface `Foo`.

---

By the way, the bounds don't serve much purpose; if you remove them your code will work just as well:

```
interface Data<M, T> {
  M modify(Modifier<M>);
  T transform(Transformer<T>);
}

interface Modifier<M> {
  M modify(InteralValue a, InternalValue b);
}

interface Transformer<T> {
  T transform(InteralValue a, InternalValue b);
}
```